# how to trim video using FFMPEG android?

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

i have tried below command but got error

```
String[] cmd = new String[14];
            cmd[0] = "-y";          
            cmd[1] = "-ss"; 
            cmd[2] = ""+videoPlayerState.getStart(); 
            cmd[3] = "-i";
            cmd[4] = inputFileName;
            cmd[5] = "-to";
            cmd[6] = ""+videoPlayerState.getDuration();
            cmd[7] = "-async";
            cmd[8] = "1";
            cmd[9] = "-strict";
            cmd[10] = "-2";
            cmd[11] = "-c";
            cmd[12] = "copy";
            cmd[13] = path + "/" + filename;
```

Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument

[mp4 @ 0xb8ce3a60] Could not find tag for codec amr_nb in stream #1, codec not currently supported in container

Comment: Like the error says, AMR NB audio not supported in MP4 by FFmpeg. After `-c copy` insert `-c:a aac`

Comment: @Mulvya can we use below code String[] cmd = new String[16];
    cmd[0] = "-y";   
    cmd[1] = "-ss"; 
    cmd[2] = ""+videoPlayerState.getStart(); 
    cmd[3] = "-i";
    cmd[4] = inputFileName;
    cmd[5] = "-to";
    cmd[6] = ""+videoPlayerState.getDuration(); 
    cmd[7] = "-async";
    cmd[8] = "1";
    cmd[9] = "-strict";
    cmd[10] = "-2";
    cmd[11] = "-c";
    cmd[12] = "copy";
    cmd[13] = "-c:a";
    cmd[14] = "aac";
    cmd[15] = path + "/" + filename;